# Ежечасовая рассылка

Tags: python

Начал писать бота для тг и испольщую pyTelegramBotAPI, столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно отправлять сообщения какждый час всем пользователям, так вот как это сделать, не стопоря остальной функционал бота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите скрипт для рассылки. Запускайте по расписанию, например `celery beat/cron`.

Таким образом это будет независимая задача. Но не забывайте про лимиты, так как используете тот же токен бота.