# Ежедневная отправка сообщений в разные дни недели

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Как бот в телеграме может ежедневно отправлять сообщения в зависимости от дней недели в группы и личные сообщения пользователей, пример: если сегодня понедельник - бот должен отправить сообщение в группу и каждому пользователю.

Пример кода:

```
if today == 'monday':
   bot.send.message('Расписание на понедельник')
```

Comment: Не уверен что сработает, но импортируй модуль time, там можно узнавать день недели, для того что бы отправлялось во все чаты нужно сделать базу данных с id чата или пользывателя.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнять определённый код раз в минуту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218055/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: ещё дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1131562/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/985863/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1232760/178576) и т.д. и т.п.